# cakephp Form helper $this->data empty

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, formhelper

I have a problem with the Form Helper that returned `$this->data` keeps being empty. In my Forms before there was no problems and I cant figure out what's different here.
For this Form there's not a model containing the data, its just user input for doing a search.

This is my View:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create();
echo $this->Form->input('Postleitzahl');
$options=array('10'=>10,'20'=>20);
echo $this->Form->input('Entfernung',array('type'=> 'select' , 'options'=>array(($options))));
echo $this->Form->end('Suchen');
?>
```

Comment: also do a `debug($this->data)` to be certain in your action

Comment: Maybe you could use it directly from $this->params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

    echo $this->Form->create(null, array('type' => 'post')); # not sure if that's needed
    echo $this->Form->input('Search.Postleitzahl');
    $options=array('10'=>10,'20'=>20);
    echo $this->Form->input('Search.Entfernung',array('options'=> $options)); # seems shorter and should work
    echo $this->Form->end('Suchen');

?>
```

The above should result into a `$this->data` array containing something similar to this:

```
['Search']
    ['Postleitzahl']: 102929
    ['Enfernung']: 'foobar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't double array your array:

```
'options'=>$options
```

Comment: changed that ...but still the same..problem , maybe it is because it doesnt represent a model in the database and i have to declare the input variables somehow ?

Comment: there should always be some model. either use a "fake" model name like "Form" in order to use the posted data in the controller - or even better use a real model with $useTable=false (this way you can have validation on your forms without using any real tables).

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily related to Cake, but the answer to the problem when I had it: if you're including a file upload in your POST, double-check that the file you're uploading isn't larger than the limit specified in your `php.ini` file.